# Correlation between two curves

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a mathematical problem in two different ways and output is a curve in both the cases. I want to compare these output curves for similarity in python. Is there any function or framework which provides this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "similar" to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 10):

The classic [Pearson's correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Pearson.27s_product-moment_coefficient) is perhaps the most popular measure of curve similarity. [SciPy](http://scipy.org/)'s [`pearsonr`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.stats.html#pearsonr) function gives you that.

Correlation coefficient measures *shape* similarity and is (somewhat, not completely) insensitive to bias and scaling.

Another way to measure similarity is to directly measure the average difference of the curves. You could use [RMS difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation). No libraries needed, simply something like this:

```
# rms difference of vectors a and b:
rmsdiff = 0
for (x, y) in zip(a, b):
    rmsdiff += (x - y) ** 2  # NOTE: overflow danger if the vectors are long!
rmsdiff = math.sqrt(rmsdiff / min(len(a), len(b))
```

RMS difference accentuates large deviations, even if they're local, and masks small deviations, even if they're global. For example, vectors

```
[1 2 3 4 5] and [2 1 4 3 6]
```

are more similar in RMS sense than

```
[1 2 3 4 5] and [1 2 3 4 2]
```

There's no one and only "right" measure of similarity. Different methods accentuate different (dis)similarities.

Comment: Correlation between two curves will be insensitive to shifts and scaling of both, so this may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @quant_dev: True, it's a bit unclear what he wants. I'll add some methods.

Comment: Thanks guys. Mine is very simple application in 2D. Scales are same for both plots. So, i don't need to worry for scaling and shifts. Thanks Joonas for answering, it solves my problem. Thanks Quant_dev for making valid point.

Comment: user14299: Functions `y = x` and functions `y = 2x + 1` have a 100 % correlation, even though the curve is completely different. Just make sure you compare your functions in a meaningful way.